# Do I need internet to emulate flutter on my phone or emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was able to create new flutter project in VSCODE and I also used internet when it got to flutter pub get part. But i kept getting this errors.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on LDN L21 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 0):

To run on Android it will download many Gradle packages. So, for the first time, you should have internet connection to run on an Android device or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Anything which demands internet during the process of the app execution will be dependent on the internet(firebase-firebase auth-online data retrieveing-etc)

However though, this is actually being caused by a missing or corrupt file which the compiler tries to read, this may be due to the an error in the creation of the project, have you tried creating it again?

Comment: Thanks for your  reply. Yes I have recreated it twice. Same issues